# TFS version control does not show conflicts

Tags: asp.net, version-control, tfs

Currently I have migrated the TFS from one hardware to another hardware and since then whenever some one check in the code and other gets that version it just replace the code with showing any alert of conflicts.

It is not merging the code just replacing it with other version.

I dont know why it is happening. Please provide your suggestion

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio/TFS are you using?

Comment: Visual studio 2013 and TFS 2013

Comment: Are you sure it is not "AutoMerged"? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181432.aspx

Comment: @KoalaBear yes I am sure

Answer (score -2):

Why not you use another file compare program for that. You can use Beyond Compare and add it in TFS. That might be more helpful for you.